# Configure warnings for mising xml comments in .editorconfig (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, xml-comments, editorconfig

is it possible to configure an `.editorconfig` file to display warnings/errors on items with missing XML documentation?

It would be great to see such warnings in the editor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which programming language are you working in?

Comment: Hi @Jimmy. I work with C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the `<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>` property in your project file (or Directory.Build.props), and have your [warning level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/warn-compiler-option) set to at least 4 (the default), that will enable warnings for [CS1591](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1591) (Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'Foo').

You can also get additional rules by adding the [StyleCop.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers/) NuGet package, which has a whole bunch of rules outlined [here](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/DocumentationRules.md) (these SA16xx rules also need the same project property enabled, or else you'll get an SA0001 warning).

These all apply to publicly exposed APIs, I'm not sure how to configure them for non-public APIs.

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy. I already thought that it won't be possible to configure all these things in one place. However, thanks for your helpful hint an the links.

Comment: Hello, could you please see also this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74763366/961631