# Combine GenerateDocumentationFile with CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member

Tags: .net, .net-core

For a .NET (core) project, is there a way to keep `GenerateDocumentationFile` and in the same time do not get **errors** like

> "CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member"

Actually in my project that is an error and not just warning. Is there a way to downgrade that error to a warning?

Comment: So was the connection string actually missing? You need to validate configuration data too. Instead of `connectionString!` you should use actually validate and throw if the connection string is missing. You could use `?? throw new ArgumentNullException` or `ArgumentException.ThrowIfNull`. .NET 7 has new features that make validation configuration objects easier

Comment: You should be very careful with book architectures too. The code used by authors is used to demonstrate the concepts in their books, not create real life applications. In real applications the database is seldom created from scratchs. After the first deployment you'll have a production DB with real data that needs to be migrated after new deployments, not replaced. There will be other applications using the same DB too, even if these are only *reports* and export jobs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I renamed the name of the connection string, in the settings and not in the code, my fault. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually I produce a stub application to be used as base for the new app creation, so I have no problem of the migration after update... But thanks for the suggestion. Should study how to migrate existing apps

Comment: Book architectures are very different from real-world architectures. Book and course authors can't cover *everything*, and neither do their examples. They only demonstrate a few things. The one you used for example doesn't cover *critical* features like logging, monitoring and healtchecks. In production, you *need* to know what's going on with your application. When something goes wrong, you *need* good logs. You need to think in advance to avoid a frantic phone call at 3 AM during your summer vacations. **Especially** if you have multiple services and/or servers

Comment: however, having nothing as base, we found that is a better way to start the clean app from an expert (we believe) code than manually creating something we are not sure about what is...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the connection string was like here https://stackoverflow.com/q/74769619/961631

Answer (score 0):

If you have such a problem it seems you have the [`TreatWarningsAsErrors` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings) enabled. In that case, you can exclude that specific [CS1591](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1591) warning to be treated as error in the project options
[image]

or edit the `.csproj` file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningsNotAsErrors>CS1591</WarningsNotAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningsNotAsErrors>CS1591</WarningsNotAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```