# Authentication error: "The provider field is required"

Tags: .net, authentication, openid-connect, azure-authentication, .net-7.0

What could be the problem I get the following when launching in localhost my .net core application:
[image]

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/Authentication/login 400 (Bad Request)

{"errors":{"provider":["The provider field is required."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1", "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-[...]-00"}
```

That is the first try for my migrated and refactored .NET 7 web api application from .NET 5, where everything worked well, I use same Azure authentication data from the "old" application:

in `secrets`:
[image]

in `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Authentication": {
    "Azure": {
      "AADInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    }
  },
```

and in `Program.cs`:

```
// ------------
// Configure Services
// ------------
string? connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServerConnection");  
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

// Identity
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Authentication
var clientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Azure:ClientId");
if (clientId == null)
    throw new System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException("Missing Azure configuration");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(
        options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Azure:ClientId");
            options.ClientSecret = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Azure:ClientSecret");
            options.Authority =
                            $"{configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Azure:AADInstance")}{configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Azure:TenantId")}";
            options.CallbackPath = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Azure:CallbackPath");
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        });
```

The Index.cshtml page that autehticate the user

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager

<body>
  <h2>Development Mode</h2>
  <p>This page is used for authentication in development mode only. It will be automatically replaced with the Angular
    generated one.</p>
  @{
    var providers = await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync();
    if (!providers.Any())
    {
      <div>
        <p>
          There are no external authentication services configured.
        </p>
      </div>
    }
    else
    {
      <form asp-controller="Authentication" asp-action="ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]"
    method="post">
        <br />
        <div>
          <p>
            @foreach (var provider in providers)
            {
              <button type="submit" name="provider" value="@provider.Name"
            title="Log in using your Azure Active Directory account">
                Azure Active Directory
              </button>
            }
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    }
  }
</body>
```

Comment: i think there is issue in Data Source name so please check that

Comment: missing Authentication:Azure:AADInstance in appsettings?

Comment: @ToreNestenius missed to add the existing `appsettings.json`, updated the OP

Comment: @UdayDodiya the datasource is the local database "localhost", the same as in the old app